# React-native UI not updating with the first onPress() trigger

Tags: javascript, react-native, event-handling, dom-events, jsx

I have facing this issue which is the UI won't update unless the second `onPress()` is triggered except the UI every thing working fine like:

```
console.log('the onPress function Has triggered')
```

Here is some of my code:

```
//JSX
 <TouchableOpacity
     
activeOpacity={.9}
                  
onPress={() => Next(i)}
                  
style={styles.nextButton}>

<Text style={styles.nextButton}> save and next</Text>
                
</TouchableOpacity>
```

```
const Next = (index) => {
    console.log('Hello world')
    let i = index + 1
    console.log(i, props.images.length)
    if (i === (props.images.length - 1)) {
      console.log('the end element !')
    }
    return (ScrollEl.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: posY, animated: true }))
  }
```

Comment: Where did you change in state?

Comment: I forget to include it in the question only I have set state in the **next function** it self     `setPos(i * Dimensions.get('window').height)`